# Firebug fixing same css?

Tags: html, css, firebug, css-position, center-align

CSS:

```
.list-a .desc-fix {
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}
.list-a .desc {
    background: url("../images/trans_black.png") repeat;
    display: block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: small;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 3px 0 0 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: 3;
    right:30px;
    left:30px
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="desc-fix">
    <span class="desc">
        <h4>Text A</h4>
        <h5>Text B</h5>
    Long text long text long text Long text long text long text Long text long text long text Long text long text long text Long text long text long textLong text long text long text Long text long text long text
    </span>
</span>
```

Above is my code to align absolute positioned span to align in middle.

But when I load the page it was not aligned in middle.

When I change(not really a change i think) any of the css to anything and changing it back to original value through Firebug it got aligned middle. Any idea, what's going on?

Comment: where is your css code?

Comment: where is `list-a` in your html code

Comment: @falguni I can see my css code at the top of the question

Comment: @Aravind30790 it is the parent of the desc-fix span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below code, wrapping those span within a class.  Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/KQ8g6/)

```
.list-a .desc-fix {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.list-a .desc {
    background: url("../images/trans_black.png") repeat;
    display: block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: small;
    margin: 3px 0 0 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width:300px;
    max-heigtht: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.list-a {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always link your css classes to their direct parent, eg:

```
.list-a span .desc-fix {)
.list-a span .desc {)
```

or simply just

```
span .desc-fix {}
span .desc {}
```

Does it work in any other browsers?

EDIT: Give this a whirl https://stackoverflow.com/a/7720742/2516336