# Place the div to the center and overlap with container div

Tags: html, css

I have a `.footerdot` div, which lies at the bottom of page with a `bluedot` image aligned to center of the page and overlapping the container div. I'm attaching the image for better understanding how the layout should looks like.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="footerdot">
   <div class="dot">
      <img src="images/bluedot.png" alt="bluedot"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Blue dot image to be placed in center and overlapping footerdot div]

Comment: Have you tried setting **margin:auto**? Perhaps you could paste your CSS code for us to look at?

Comment: Hi Guys, Thank you very much for the help. Your suggestions and comments helped me to dig a little bit more and I found the right answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720730/how-to-align-the-absolute-position-to-center

Answer (score 0):

From the image I understand that you are trying to create a slider. The `footerdot` acts as the slider base and the dot is used to slide over it.

This includes overlapping the `dot` over `footerdot`. So to overlap a div over another div, we need to place both `footerdot` and `dot` inside another `parentdiv` with `position: relative`.

Now both the child divs are relayively positioned to their `parentdiv`. The flow will be normal here.

In order to place `dot` over `footerdot`, i.e we are not altering the position of `footerdot` but the `dot`. So we need to position the `dot` absolutely to it's parent. Add `position:absolute` to `dot`. Now `dot` overlaps the `footerdot`. Give `dot` a fixed width and height. eg: `height: 20px; width: 20px`.

But `dot` is still not centered on the `footerdot`. Instead it lies on the top left corner. In order to achieve that we need to add a `dotparent` div to the `dot`, which takes the width of the `footerdot` and we can center the `dot` inside it. But again we also need to shift the property `position: absolute` from `dot` to `dotparent`. And add `left: 0; right: 0` to `dotparent`, so that it occupies the whole width of the parent from left to right. Now the width of `dotparent` is same as `footerdot`.  `dot` can be centered inside the `dotparent` by applying `margin: 0 auto` on `dot`.

Finally the Html structure:

```
<div class='parentdiv'><div class='footerdot'></div><div class='parentdot'><div class='dot'></div></div></div>
```